# Apk crash information

Tags: android, xamarin, exception, logging, apk

I have a built an Android app with Xamarin (v4) and packaged and signed the APK with Visual Studio 2019. I have transferred the APK to five of my own Android devices and they all run the app fine. However, I have sent the APK to another person for usage, and it crashes immediately on their device (App has stopped working). Since I have limited access to the other person's device, I cannot connect it to debug mode and see if I can get some information about the application crash.

Is there some log in Android or somewhere where one can find more information about a recent app crash (without entering debug with Visual Studio), typically something that you could ask somebody to extract?

Comment: use appcenter.ms

Comment: If other device crashed when open the application at the first time. please check the permission if are granted.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics, it's pretty much industry standard these days. You will have good insight into when/where/probably also why crash happened.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use android studio (is better than VisualStudio)
2. You can save Log in your locale database on device, and you can add new activity for send report about app. Send this report to your mail, and add an attachment (this attachment is a .txt file with your log. Obvious after add attachment, read logs saved in database).
3. Add many try catch to save log and to manage your bug.

Sorry for my English.